# No video on integrated DP Dell OptiPlex 790 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display, dell

I'm having some difficulties when I plug a second screen to the DP on a Dell OptiPlex 790. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. It detects the screen but no video.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just realized that when I print screen it shows both screens but the screen The screen does not give video.